# Multithread C qsort char array

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mmap, qsort

I am trying to sort some records by their keys in C.

There are **M** number of records, and each record's syntax is:

**KEY v**     -------- **DATA v**

1234abcd. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzzzzzzzzz

Each record has an 8 byte hex key value, followed by 64 bytes of data

The process is as follows:

- open a file
- create memory map of file
- now in memory with the giant char *, create N threads
- use **N** threads to qsort **M/N** records
- merge adjacent sorted partitions ie. 0 and 1, 2 and 3

Right now I am trying to target the key in the qsort function, but I am getting a segmentation fault.

My code after successfully opening the file.

```
if((fstat(fileNum, &sb)) == -1) {
         printf("fstat fail");
         exit(-1);
    }  
int sb_size = sb.st_size;
int num_records = sb_size/REC_SIZE;

printf("SB SIZE: %d\n", sb_size);
printf("num_records: %d\n", num_records);

addr = (char *)mmap(NULL, sb_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fileNum, 0);

if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
    close(fileNum);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int num_records_per_thread = num_records/num_threads;
printf("Number of Records per Thread = %d\n", num_records_per_thread);
qsort(addr, num_records_per_thread, REC_SIZE, compare);

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
        struct mRecord rec1, rec2;
        char *keya;
        strncpy(keya, (char *)a, 8);
        printf("in Compare: first 8 bytes are: %s", keya);
        return 1;
    }
```

This gives me a segmentation fault. How can I just target the keys and sort them?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but when checking `errno` do it immediately after the failing function call, most importantly don't call another function which might alter `errno` in between. I'm mention this because if `mmap` fail you call `close`, which might *also* fail and therefore alter the `errno` value. Call `perror` before `close`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You may not copy the variable a on keya using strncpy, because keya is a pointer that is not initialized!

2) The function compare has to return a value of a comparison!

Then inside the function compare you may write:

```
return strncmp( (char *)a, (char *)b, 8 ); //8 is the key length!
```

Comment: I should have clarified. I did not yet implement the compare function. I just wanted to see what the data coming into the function looked like. If i did printf("a = %s", a); I would get the entire char array, and not just the single record. The sort does not work.

Comment: Ok! Then you have to declare: char keya[9], not char * keya. If you use char * keya it points random in memory, it's not assigned! (I think also strncpy shall be different maybe 9 and not 8 - but I'm not sure)

Comment: Ah figured it out. I did the debugging with char test[8] = a and I found the issue was with my record size. Thank you SO much